# Add Share Button to Naviagtion Bar

Tags: ios, webview, share

I'd like to add a share button to the navigation bar in a webview that when pressed gives the options to open the link in Safari, Email the link, share on facebook, tweet it.  Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to go about this?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), did you search for it?

Comment: I have searched for it but haven't found anything yet.  I'm still searching though.

Answer (score 0):

Try [BCDShareSheet](https://github.com/jmacmullin/BCDShareSheet). It includes sharing with Email, Twitter, and Facebook, but it lacks opening in Safari, but it should be trivial to add it.